# How to convert nested object into Json in Delphi 10.1 berlin

Tags: json, delphi, json-serialization

I am very much new in delphi. Presently I am facing a problem. i want to convert nested object into Json using TJson, but having memory related issue.

Here is my code.

It is just simple unit file with Person and Address class. The person class is depended on the address class.

```
unit uPerson;

interface

uses
  REST.Json;

type
  TAddress = class
  private
    FStreetNAme: string;
    FState: string;
    FPinCode: string;
  published
    property StreetNAme: string read FStreetNAme write FStreetNAme;
    property State: string read FState write FState;
    property PinCode: string read FPinCode write FPinCode;
  end;

  TPerson = class
  private
    FName: string;
    FAge: Integer;
    FSalary: Double;
    [JSONMarshalled(True)]
    FAddress: TAddress;
  published
    property Name: string read FName write FName;
    property Age: Integer read FAge write FAge;
    property Salary: Double read FSalary write FSalary;
    property Address: TAddress read FAddress write FAddress;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

Below is the main form code

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, uPerson,
  REST.JSON;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    edtName: TLabeledEdit;
    edtAge: TLabeledEdit;
    edtSalary: TLabeledEdit;
    edtStreet: TLabeledEdit;
    edtState: TLabeledEdit;
    edtPin: TLabeledEdit;
    btnSave: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;


var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Person: TPerson;
  Add: TAddress;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  jsonString: string;
begin
  Person := TPerson.Create;
  try
    Person.Name := edtName.Text;
    Person.Age := Integer.Parse(edtAge.Text);
    Person.Salary := double.Parse(edtSalary.Text);

    Add.StreetNAme := edtStreet.Text;
    Add.State := edtState.Text;
    Add.PinCode := edtPin.Text;

    Person.Address := Add;

    jsonString := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(Person);
    Memo1.Text := jsonString;

  finally
    Add.Free;
    Person.Free;
  end;
  //
end;

end.
```

The code is compiling properly. But when try to generate the json it is giving access violation error. Here is the image - [access violation error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP5xq.png)

**[Update]**
Basically I am getting "access violation at 0x00409fca: write of address 0x00000004".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please could you include the error message as part of the question and in text, not a screenshot.

Comment: @RichardHunter yes sir. From next time onward I will add error message in text. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about the JSON facilities, but I do know Delphi memory management.

And this error is expected, because you forget to create the `TAddress` object.

The first problem is this line:

```
Add.StreetNAme := edtStreet.Text;
```

`Add` is a global variable, so it initially is set to `nil` (since it is an object pointer). Consequently, you here try to write to a memory address very close to `0`, which is precisely what you see in the exception message.

You need to create a `TAddress` object on the heap and assign the address of this object to the `Add` variable.

Just like you do for the `TPerson` object.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  jsonString: string;
begin
  Person := TPerson.Create;
  try
    Add := TAddress.Create;
    try
      Person.Name := edtName.Text;
      Person.Age := Integer.Parse(edtAge.Text);
      Person.Salary := double.Parse(edtSalary.Text);
  
      Add.StreetName := edtStreet.Text;
      Add.State := edtState.Text;
      Add.PinCode := edtPin.Text;
  
      Person.Address := Add;
  
      jsonString := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(Person);
      Memo1.Text := jsonString;
    finally
      Add.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Person.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Also, it's not a good idea to use global variables here. Instead, use local variables. And there is no need for a separate `TAddress` variable at all:

```pascal
var
  Person: TPerson;
  jsonString: string;
begin
  Person := TPerson.Create;
  try
    Person.Address := TAddress.Create;
    try
      Person.Name := edtName.Text;
      Person.Age := Integer.Parse(edtAge.Text);
      Person.Salary := double.Parse(edtSalary.Text);

      Person.Address.StreetName := edtStreet.Text;
      Person.Address.State := edtState.Text;
      Person.Address.PinCode := edtPin.Text;

      jsonString := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(Person);
      Memo1.Text := jsonString;
    finally
      Person.Address.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Person.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Furthermore, you might argue that it would be better if the `TPerson` constructor created a `TAddress` object and put a pointer to it in its `Address` field. Then the `TPerson` destructor would also be responsible for freeing this object:

```pascal
unit uPerson;

interface

uses
  REST.Json;

type
  TAddress = class
  private
    FStreetNAme: string;
    FState: string;
    FPinCode: string;
  published
    property StreetNAme: string read FStreetNAme write FStreetNAme;
    property State: string read FState write FState;
    property PinCode: string read FPinCode write FPinCode;
  end;

  TPerson = class
  private
    FName: string;
    FAge: Integer;
    FSalary: Double;
    [JSONMarshalled(True)]
    FAddress: TAddress;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Name: string read FName write FName;
    property Age: Integer read FAge write FAge;
    property Salary: Double read FSalary write FSalary;
    property Address: TAddress read FAddress write FAddress;
  end;

implementation

{ TPerson }

constructor TPerson.Create;
begin
  FAddress := TAddress.Create;
end;

destructor TPerson.Destroy;
begin
  FAddress.Free;
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

and

```pascal
var
  Person: TPerson;
  jsonString: string;
begin
  Person := TPerson.Create;
  try
    Person.Name := 'Andreas';
    Person.Age := 32;
    Person.Salary := 12345;

    Person.Address.StreetName := 'Street';
    Person.Address.State := 'State';
    Person.Address.PinCode := 'pin';

    jsonString := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(Person);
    Memo1.Text := jsonString;
  finally
    Person.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you @Andreas Rejbrand. It is silly of me that I forget to create Address object. The post is and will be helpful for beginners like me.